bug? anchor build got error: `Stack offset of 4608 exceeded max offset of 4096 ...` if there is v1.18.10 solana, but v1.16.25 is OK
Question1:
anchor build got error: Stack offset of 4608 exceeded max offset of 4096 ... if let solana v1.18.10 present in ENV/PATH
 ❱❱❱ which solana
/mnt/volume2/solana_dev_env/v1.18.10/solana-release/bin/solana
 ❱❱❱  echo $PATH         
/mnt/volume2/solana_dev_env/v1.18.10/solana-release/bin:/home/ubuntu/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/sbin: ...

(events) ❱❱❱ anchor build                                                   
info: uninstalling toolchain 'solana'
info: toolchain 'solana' uninstalled
warning: virtual workspace defaulting to `resolver = "1"` despite one or more workspace members being on edition 2021 which implies `resolver = "2"`
note: to keep the current resolver, specify `workspace.resolver = "1"` in the workspace root's manifest
note: to use the edition 2021 resolver, specify `workspace.resolver = "2"` in the workspace root's manifest
note: for more details see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/resolver.html#resolver-versions
   Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.79

...

   Compiling anchor-attribute-program v0.28.0
   Compiling anchor-attribute-error v0.28.0
   Compiling anchor-derive-space v0.28.0
   Compiling base64 v0.13.1
Error: Function _ZN112_$LT$solana_program..instruction..InstructionError$u20$as$u20$solana_frozen_abi..abi_example..AbiEnumVisitor$GT$13visit_for_abi17hd196cb48ec8b8db8E Stack offset of 4608 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 512 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
Error: Function _ZN108_$LT$solana_program..vote..state..CircBuf$LT$I$GT$$u20$as$u20$solana_frozen_abi..abi_example..AbiExample$GT$7example17h4b696142e261c9f4E Stack offset of 4640 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 544 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
   Compiling anchor-lang v0.28.0
            ...

but anchor build build output .so file without error if let v1.16.25 solana present in ENV/PATH.
(events) ❱❱❱  solana --version
solana-cli 1.16.25 (src:8dd7d060; feat:2294205250, client:SolanaLabs)
(events) ❱❱❱ anchor build 
info: uninstalling toolchain 'solana'
            ...

Need to mention that, in both case, my anchor cli version is 0.29.0
(events) ❱❱❱ anchor --version
anchor-cli 0.29.0 
(events) ❱❱❱ which anchor
/home/ubuntu/.cargo/bin/anchor 
(events) ❱❱❱ 

Question2:
This is my first time notice the build log "uninstalling toolchain 'solana' ", what does it mean? does anchor build action remove old solana and installed it's own solana ? I doubt. but this log message puzzled me.
(events) ❱❱❱ anchor build                                                   
info: uninstalling toolchain 'solana'
info: toolchain 'solana' uninstalled


Copying my answer at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/issues/1285:
Be sure to use the newest solana-program crate in your project if you don't want the error, since this was fixed awhile ago. Here's the fixed state in 1.18 in https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/f3fa655000c8f436eac0283ef71be1fe1211eb41/sdk/program/src/instruction.rs#L31
On top of that, I can guarantee that your program compiled successfully, so you can feel free to use it even when those errors are reported.

Thanks. I try again, use v1.18 solana cli and still got same error. Then I found the root cause is my project's Cargo.lock file, it was stale, delete it and redo build then success.
